# Web interface for BIND DNS and DHCPD servers

Tags: linux, dns, isc-dhcpd

Currently we are using the BIND DNS and the standard DHCP server that comes with Linux (Scientific 6.4) as networking services on a private networking. Is there any some kind of a web interface that reads existing configuration files (`/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` and `/var/local/zone-name.zone`) instead of manually writing to these files?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com); it is a web interface with several modules that enables you to administer visually a lot of Linux services. It is very simple to use.

If you have multiple users, you can also create users with modules views, and some modules let you make further user restrictions.

At the DNS module level, you can even restrict them to specific DNS zones. For instance, user1 can only edit the zone xpto.com and restart the DNS server.

To install it in a RH flavoured distro:

```
yum install webmin
```

or in Debian:

```
apt-get install webmin
```